# Firebase: Cómo actualizar el Inventario si hay usuarios Offline?

Tags: firebase, flutter, transacciones

Tengo un App para el Agro construida con Flutter y Firebase. El App funciona de la siguiente forma:

1. Tiene un Inventario de Alimento en Bodega
2. Los usuarios salen a alimentar en modo Offline (están en una granja)
3. Después regresan y la escritura de la base se ejecuta conforme las propiedades Offline de Firebase

Cuando los usuarios están online al momento de alimentar, todo funciona perfecto, pero cuando alimentan en modo Offline tengo un problema específicamente al momento de actualizar el inventario, dado que el inventario en caché del usuario Offline puede estar diferente del inventario real en bodega (ya sea porque ha entrado nuevo alimento o por las actualizaciones en línea de otros usuarios al momento de alimentar).

La forma como estoy escribiendo los datos en Firebase (usando patrón BLOC y PROVIDER) es la siguiente:

```
  Future<bool> actualizarCantidad(String idAlimento, double cantidadActualizada) async {
  try {
      db.child('alimento/$idAlimento').update({ "cantidad": cantidadActualizada});
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return true;
  }
```

La función donde se lee el inventario y se ordena la actualización de la base es la siguiente:

```
Future<void> _submit() async {

    _alimento = await alimentoBloc.cargarAlimento(alimentar.idAlimento); 
    //Lee el inventario para el tipo de alimento en específico (alimentar.idAlimento)

    final _cantAlimento = _alimento.cantidad - _consumoTotal; 
    //_alimento.cantidad es la cantidad de alimento en el inventario
    //_consumoTotal es la cantidad total consumida por los animales 

    _alimentoBloc.actualizarCantidad(alimentar.idAlimento, _cantAlimento);
    //Es la función que actualiza el inventario con la nueva cantidad (_cantAlimento)
}
```

Lo que quisiera hacer en Firebase es que en lugar de asignar _cantAlimento al Inventario, ejecute algo como "**disminuya _consumoTotal del número en Inventario**" y de esa forma no importaría si el usuario está Offline u Online. **Es esto posible?**

Otra alternativa que he revisado es usar Transacciones para asegurar que está usando el último dato, pero las transacciones se pierden cuando el usuario está offline, así que no es una posibilidad.

**Cómo podría actualizar el Inventario de la forma correcta, teniendo en cuenta que mis usuarios muchas veces están Offline?**

Comment: para ese caso no sería adecuado usar firestore offline, lo que podrías hacer es hacer tu propio manejador de datos offline.  Detecta cuando el usuario está offline, entonces ahí las peticiones que ya no vayan contra firestore sino contra tu manejador local, luego cuando detectes que hay internet nuevamente,  puedes implementar tu propia lógica para sincronizar datos.

Comment: No hay forma en Firebase de hacer un write del tipo "incremente el dato almacenado en xxx"?

Comment: hmm no estoy seguro, con cloud functions si, pero sería online.

Comment: Tienes alguna referencia donde se observe un manejador de datos offline? Supongo que antes de escribir se pregunta si está offline, si lo está, lo deja en una tabla de transacciones pendientes, algo así?

Comment: hay bastante info en la web, solo pon  Flutter offline , y verás mucha info : https://medium.com/flutter-community/offline-first-with-flutter-be1e8335d976